# ie6/7 script tag population giving "unexpected call to method or property access"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I use AJAX to get the content of a script, and then use the following code:

```
    var scr = document.createElement('script');
    scr.appendChild(document.createTextNode(script)); // ***
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scr);
```

Where `script` is astring populated from AJAX. This works fine in IE9, Chrome and Firefox. However, in IE6 and 7 I get an error:

> Unexpected call to method or property access

IE gives the number of the the line indicated with the `// ***`.

Although there are multiple other questions about this, none of the appear to address this precise issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Older IE's do not accept child nodes in script elements ( or in style and option elements, but that's another two questions).

You can set the script element's text property instead.
(scripttext is a string of, well, script text.)

```
var scr = document.createElement('script');
if(window.addEventListener)scr.appendChild(document.createTextNode(script))
else scr.text=scripttext;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scr);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the code in a string, why make a script tag out of it?  Can't you just call `eval(script)` on it.  Won't that do the same thing?

Comment: Because I can get much better tracebacks in Chrome and Firefox and IE8+ if I use <script> instead of eval.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]****;****.appendChild(scr);

Why did you put a semicolon here?

Comment: Good catch, that was a mistake in simplifying the code for SO.